# handling property value that throws an exception

Tags: c#, exception, properties

I'm having a bit of an issue with a c# property throwing an exception when checking for null.
I don't have access to the class that contains the property causing this issue, otherwise it would be an easy fix.

Basically, I have a view model that contains Imported_Class. The Imported_Class is populated with a method in a shared library. I ran into an issue when a property from Imported_Class throws an exception instead of returning null or a value.

It doesn't crash the app, I just can't check for null to prevent any possible errors.

I could assign that property to a local variable, wrapped in a try/catch to catch the error, but I find that too clunky just for one property.

An example of my issue:

```
public string getPropertyA
{
  get { return Imported_Class.PropertyA; /* throws exception */ }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: There aren't TONS of options, either you let the exception blow up your PC or you catch it.

Comment: `an exception` could be anything. What is the exception?

Comment: Which exception is thrown? If it's a nullreferenceexception probably Imported_Class is null and has nothing to do with the object's property

Comment: I already told you one of my solutions for it (wrapping it in a try/catch), albeit not a very efficient one, because this Imported_Class is being used in numerous places, not just a single location. It would be nice to find a more efficient way of handling it, that's all I'm asking really.

Comment: I believe Bill is saying that the Imported_Class is fine, but the get accessor of the property is throwing the exception.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, Gusman, it is throwing a null reference exception.

Comment: Yes, brader24 :) that is exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Imported_Class doesn't provide a public way for you to test for the condition before getting the property, then I don't think there is any other choice than to wrap the call in a try/catch block.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to avoid this, but I guess I'll have to stick with it unfortunately. Thank you for the quick response!